# Aws lambda + Api Gateway issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have one AWS lambda function, which is in node.js

```
var pg = require("pg");
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 var client = new pg.Client({
    user: "41231qd123",
    password: "lkjlkasjdlkasldkjas",
    database: "12312312asdasd",
    port: 5432,
    host: "kdoiedjeifk.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
    ssl: true
 }); 
 client.connect();
 console.log('Connected to PostgreSQL database');
 client.query("SELECT products.* from products where location_id = 
  "+event.location_id+" AND company_id = "+event.company_id+" order  
   by products.name ASC;", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(res.rows);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    console.log(jsonString);
    client.end();
    context.succeed(jsonObj);
  });
};
```

When i test this function in aws lambda "Test", it was working perfectly, but after i added the api-gateway and test it ther i am getting this message 'Process exited before completing request', is there any specific reason with the code or configuration?

[image: Image shows the response when i test it through api-gateway]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your API Gateway Integration Request look like?  Is it setup to be a `LAMBDA_PROXY` integration?

Comment: Your API log response says that your task timed out (fourth log line from the bottom). Try upping the timeout on your lambda to 25 seconds to see if that's enough time to get a response without a timeout. It is really weird that the duration you posted in your logs is <1s, though.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your logs for a lambda error.

**If there is no lambda crash**

If the function is taking longer than 29 seconds then the API Gateway integration can time out. Check the lambda logs to see if there is a crash there, and if not check the time taken.

**If there is a lambda crash**

Your lambda logs in cloudwatch will give a better reason why. "Process exited before completing request" is usually the boilerplate AWS Lambda error for a limits error. You likely either:

1. Ran out of memory in the lambda VM
2. Ran out of disk space in the lambda VM
3. Timed out.

Check the REPORT line of your logs, they should look like this:

`REPORT RequestId: asdf-wertvgh-12345-fdghdfgh Duration: 12345.13 ms Billed Duration: 12400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 64 MB`

If that isn't the error, your logs should give you some idea of what happened. Posting a traceback might help.